# django-allauth twitter oauth2 Missing valid authorization header

Tags: django, twitter

Trying to setup a Django 4.2 app with django-allauth for Twitter using OAuth2.

The user gets presented the Twitter Authorize page with the correct logo an account name but after the user clicks on the "Authorize App" button the following message is shown:

Details: unknown, Error: Error retrieving access token: b'{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Missing valid authorization header"}'

Any ideas on how to fix the Missing valid authorization header?

The package versions are:
django 4.2
django-allauth 0.54.0

The settings.py INSTALLED APPS
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter_oauth2',

I think settings in the Twitter API are setup properly as this Twitter App is being used successfully for non-Django operations (collect, tweet, etc).

I've also double-checked the callback url which is the standard https://domain/accounts/twitter_oauth2/login/callback/

The Twitter docs
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token
say for confidential clients (which this is, as it is a simple web app) the header should have  Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

I think the error message from Twitter is saying the request does not have the Authorization: Basic info .   And I do not know how to set this up.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers, Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Did you see some special tokens? I didn't work with Twitter auth—it died when I tryed to register my number—but when you add auth with Google you need to add special tokens in `settings.py`:

```
 'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile', 
            'email'
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'},
        'SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL': True,
        'APP': {
            'client_id': os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
            'secret': os.environ.get('GOOGLE_SECRET'),
            'key': ''
        }
    },}
```

They lie in the place with name `~crediatials` or "APIs & services" (for Google).

Also, you can try to add this special token in `Authorization`.

Comment: Did u work with google auth?

Comment: I don't think twitter_oath2 uses the SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS in the settings.py.  https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#twitter-oauth2 I did use the SOCIAL_ACCOUNT_PROVIDERS  when setting up Facebook and that works fine.   The only setup i did for twitter_oauth2 was through the admin screens in the Social Applications for the Twitter provider where I set the Client Id and secret keys with the values shown in the Twitter App key screen.  Similar to how the site worked with the older twitter provider (not twitter_oath2).  I haven't tried google (but FB - works fine).

Comment: Jermey,  Yesterday I enabled Google as a provider and it worked perfectly, first-time, following the simple instructions in the docs: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google  .  So right now my site has Twitter (using Oauth1) and Google with the nicer Oauth2.   I am still looking for help with Twitter Oauth2.